"Couldn't connect to server" outside of the server
I have a VPS instance running FreeBSD. I started a simple web server on port 80.
When I am ssh'd into the server, I can reach the server:
$ curl <server-ip-address>
hello

However, when I try to connect on my own device:
$ curl http://<server-ip-address>
curl: (28) Failed to connect to <server-ip-address> port 80 after 8710 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I have searched on how to fix it, but have thusfar not been able to solve it.
Here's some information that might be useful:

Running ifconfig vtnet0 returns inet <server-ip-address>
This IP address is the same address as my VPS provides shows in the server management tool
My firewall (using pf) (pf.conf):

## Set public interface ##
ext_if = "vtnet0"

## Set server public IP address
ext_if_ip = "<server-ip-address>"

## Set and drop IP ranges on public interface ##
martians = "{ 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, \
              10.0.0.0/8, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.0.2.0/24, \
              0.0.0.0/8, 240.0.0.0/4 }"

## Set http (80) and https (443) ports ##
webports = "{http, https}"

## enable services ##
int_tcp_services = "{domain, ntp, smtp, www, https, ftp, ssh}"
int_udp_services = "{domain, ntp}"

## Skip loop back interface ##
set skip on lo

## Sets the interface for which PF should gather statistics such as bytes in/o
set loginterface $ext_if

## Set default policy ##
block return in log all
block out all

# Drop all Non-Routable Addresses
block drop in quick on $ext_if from $martians to any
block drop out quick on $ext_if from any to $martians

## Blocking spoofed packets
antispoof quick for $ext_if

# Allow SSH from any IP address
pass in inet proto tcp to $ext_if port ssh

# Allow Ping-Pong stuff. Be a good sysadmin
pass inet proto icmp icmp-type echoreq

# All access to our Nginx/Apache/Lighttpd Webserver ports
pass proto tcp from any to $ext_if port $webports

# Allow essential outgoing traffic
pass out quick on $ext_if proto tcp to any port $int_tcp_services
pass out quick on $ext_if proto udp to any port $int_udp_services


Last 2 entries of tcpdum -n -e -ttt -r /var/log/pflog

 00:01:06.020635 rule 0/0(match): block in on vtnet0: <some-ip-address (not mine)> > <server-ip-address>: Flags [S], seq 3213013147, win 64240, options [mss 1460, [|tcp]
 00:02:17.580326 rule 0/0(match): block in on vtnet0: <some-ip-address (not mine)> > <server-ip-address>: Flags [S], seq 3170210564, win 65535, length 0

Any help is much appreciated as I've hit a roadblock on trying to fix this.

Does that simple web server listen on <server-ip-address>?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity It does. I started the web server like so: python -m http.server -b <server-ip-address> 80. Curl-ing to the ip address on the server gives a response, on my local machine it does not.

@schrodingerscatcuriosity thanks for the heads up, I edited my post

But curl localhost that you show is not curl-ing the ip address, and I don't know pythons http.server module, so I can't tell if that is the right way to start that. But I maintain that what you show is consistent with a server process only listening on 127.0.0.1 and not on the ip address of the server.
